# List of servers in multiple groups

Tags: powershell

I have a list of servers and each one has a group name associated with it. I'm trying to create a text output that lists the group name then below that all of the servers with that group designation.

I have a write-output that does the following:

```
Group1
Server1
Group1
Server2
```

But I need the following:

```
Group1
Server1
Server2
```

Been trying out many different directions but here is one from the write-output example:

```
$servers = Import-CSV c:\dev.csv | ForEach-Object {

Write-Output "@

    $($_.Group)
    $($_.Name)

"@ } > c:\dev.ini
```

Comment: Don't you need Get-Group : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-group

Comment: What format has the csv file that you are importing?